# Excel InterOp: How to WorkBook.SaveAs using absolute path when ":" is not allowed?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm trying to save a workbook from memory using the following code:

```
 this.Target.WorkBook.SaveAs(this.Target.WorkBookPath, Interop.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                         Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                          Interop.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                         Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
```

Where this.Target.WorkBookPath is read from the config file as:

> D:\Devzone\rpt_SalesMargins2

But Im getting this error message:

> The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:\n\n• Make
>   sure the specified folder exists. \n• Make sure the folder that
>   contains the file is not read-only.\n• Make sure the file name does
>   not contain any of the following characters:  <  >  ?  [  ]  :  | or 
>   *\n• Make sure the file/path name doesn't contain more than 218 characters.

So if I cant use ":" then how can I specify D:\ ?

**UPDATE / SANITY CHECK**

[image: config]

[image: SANITY]

In this image the file is called rego, i have tried several random names and all work as relative paths but fail when absoluted.

Comment: Are you sure you need to escape that backslash in your config file?  Have you tried debugging the path value to check its what you expect?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685344/do-i-need-to-escape-backslash-in-a-config-file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is with the : as a drive separator.  From Microsoft Support:

> For example, the path for a file might resemple the following:
>      'c:\excel\personal...[my workbook.xls]up_to_31_char_sheetname'!$A$1
>
> Note This behavior will also occur if there is a **square bracket** in the path. *(emphasis mine)*

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213983

They use an example of a bad path that includes a drive letter and say the *bad thing* is the *[* in the path.

What is the full path you are trying to use?

Comment: It's D:\Devzone\rpt_SalesMargins2. If i just use rpt_SalesMargins2 it doesn't fail but saves it to the current directory.

Comment: Are you **sure** you are properly escaping backslashes in your string? If you don't escape property, look what you get: D:\Devzone **\r** pt_SalesMargins2.  `\r` is a carriage return...

Comment: Configuration key is escaped. Ive simplified it and it still fails: <add key="CustomerSalesMarginReportData" value="D:\\rego" />. This works however: <add key="CustomerSalesMarginReportData" value="rego" />. It actually saves it to My Documents, not the current working directory as i said in my first comment. I will paste an immediate window graphic into my question so you can be sure im not running you in circles